# Buscador en tiempo real solo muestra resultados en el primer modal

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

tengo un problema que no logro entender. en mi sitio estoy imprimiendo información sobre distintas habitaciones de hotel en una ventana modal de boostrap.
Dentro de cada modal se muestra información distinta pero tiene un Buscador de productos en tiempo real.
El problema es que el buscador solo arroja resultados en la primera ventana modal.
Abro la segunda ventana modal y lo que escriba para buscar lo muestra solo en el primer Modal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que ocupo:

```
<button style=" background-color: transparent;
        border: none;" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal{{ $habitacion->id }}"> </button>

<div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="registerModal{{$habitacion->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 @include('livewire.buscador-productos')

</div>
```

**Buscador-Productos.blade.php**

```
<div wire:ignore>

<form  action="#" id="search-form">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" id="search-wrapper">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 m-0 search" placeholder="What are you looking for .. ">

            <div  id="results">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Js:

```
  <script>
    $(function ()
    {
        'use strict';

        $(document).on('keyup', '#search-form .search', function ()
        {
            if($(this).val().length > 0)
            {
                var search = $(this).val();

                $.get("{{ route('posts.search') }}", {search: search}, function (res)
                {
                    $('#results').html(res);
                });

                return;
            }

            $('#results').empty();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.post-link', function ()
        {
            var postId = $(this).data('id');

            $.get("{{ url('posts/show') }}", {id: postId}, function (res)
            {
                $('#results').empty();
                $('.search').val('');
                $('#post').html(res);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**Como puedo hacer que los resultados se muestren en todas las ventanas modal?**
Los productos son los mismos para todas las habitaciones

Comment: El problema se da porque estas usando el mismo `id` en todos los modals. El `id` deber ser único y por eso siempre toma el primer elemento.

Comment: @Marcos Hola marcos, pero arriba en el header del modal sale Habitacion 1 y 2. esas son las id distintas. a eso te refieres?

Comment: Se refiere al TAG del HTML que no muestras en tu código, el que genera las modales, debe de ser único y será algo así: id="modal"

Comment: @JeremiasRosas, me refiero a que por lo que detallas en tu pregunta tenes un modal por cada "Habitacion". Correcto? Entonces cuando se abre el modal para la "Habitacion 1", tenes un elemento con `id="search-form"` y otro con `id="results"`. Luego "Habitación 2", de nuevo tenes elementos con los mismos `id`.

Comment: @Marcos Actualice mi post, puse como genero el modal con el id

Comment: @JeremiasRosas, el problema no es el `id` del modal, sino el `id` de los elementos dentro de los modal. Por lo que se ve cada modal tienen `id` distinto, ya que le agregas `$habitacion->id` para que no se repitan.

Comment: @Marcos ya, pero como lo soluciono para que el buscador tenga un id distinto? perdón por mi falta de experiencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da porque estas creando un modal por cada habitación y dentro de cada modal el `id` de los elementos se esta repitiendo. El `id` deber ser único y por eso siempre toma el primer elemento.

> El atributo global `id` define un identificador único (ID) el cual no debe repetirse en todo el documento. Su propósito es identificar el elemento al vincularlo (usando un identificador de fragmento), en scripts u hojas de estilo (con CSS).

Fuente: [MDN > HTML > id](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

#### Solución:

Para poder identificar los elementos dentro de cada modal, podrías usar el atributo `class` e indicar una clase distinta para cada elemento.

##### Ejemplo:

En el `HTML` reemplazamos los `id` con `class` y agregamos el nombre de una clase a gusto.

```html
<!-- Indicamos en "class" una clase -->
<form  action="#" class="search-form">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Indicamos en "class" una clase -->
        <div class="col-12" class="search-wrapper">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 m-0 search" placeholder="What are you looking for .. ">

            <!-- Indicamos en "class" una clase -->
            <div class="search-results"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

En `JS` modificamos la asignación de eventos y sus callbacks para que, dependiendo desde "donde" (*su contexto*) se dispara, podamos afectar los elementos correctos.

```js
    $(function() {
      'use strict';

      $(document).on('keyup', '.search-form .search', function() {
        let $input = $(this),
          // Desde el input buscamos en sus ancestros el from mas cercano
          $form = $input.closest('.search-form'),
          // Desde el from buscamos en sus descendientes el contenedor
          $results = $form.find('.search-results');
        
        if ($input.val().length > 0) {
          var search = $input.val();

          $.get("{{ route('posts.search') }}", {
            search: search
          }, function(res) {
            $results.html(res);
          });

          return;
        }

        $results.empty();
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.post-link', function() {
        let $link = $(this),
          postId = $link.data('id'),
          // Desde el "post" buscamos el form mas cercano
          $form = $link.closest('.search-form'),
          $input = $form.find('.search-input'),
          $results = $form.find('.search-results');

        $.get("{{ url('posts/show') }}", {
          id: postId
        }, function(res) {
          $results.empty();
          $input.val('');
          $('#post').html(res); // @TODO revisar si esto es correcto
        });
      });
    });
```

**PD:** Como te comente, considero que tener un modal por cada habitación no es una buena idea por toda la sobrecarga que esto implica. Con un solo modal deberías poder lograr el mismo resultado.

Comment: Hola @Marcos, puedes ayudarme a mejorar mi codigo?, tienes razón con que sobrecarga todo. ¿Como puedo utilizar un solo modal y que a su vez muestre las información de distintas habitaciones?

Comment: Hola @JeremiasRosas, tendrías que: 1.- Tener un único modal con un `id`. 2.- asignar a los botones que abren el modal una única función la cual tomaría el `id` de post, lo guardaría en una variable accesible fuera de su contexto (_pseudo-global_) y abriría el modal. Luego solo te quedaría leer dicha variable a la hora de buscar